# getting user likes in facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I am trying to get user likes in facebook. I can only get 100 at a time for some reason. i tried using the limit parameter in open graph syntax and it didn't help. I alwso tried writing an FQL query to get more likes and to no avail. No matter what I do, i get only 100 likes per request. It's even worse. Most of the likes are of no interest to me. I'm using only likes on several categories. if i could have gotten (using FQL) 100 likes of a user which are all of those categories, that would have been sufficient to me. But when I call the FQL query it seems that FB is querying on 100 first likes and returning the results instead of returning 100 results. I am despaired at this mechanism, is there a way out of this or is FB really gave no way to get more likes in a single call?

Answer (score 1):

Read about paging in the docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.2?locale=en_GB#paging

I guess the max limit is 100, if you want to get more than that you have to make another call by using paging. There is no way to filter with the API, you will have to do that on your own after getting the likes.

Comment: Thanks. I know all about paging though, I also know that you can in fact filter through the API as I explained in my question (using FQL). The problem is that 100 likes per request sounds a bit ... small. And i can't find that it is in fact the max limit anywhere

Comment: to me it sounds very high, to be honest. the default is 25 afaik.

Comment: it is 25. Anyway I thank you for trying to help :) I think I have no other choice then to make multiple calls